# .Net - Read out current network interface throughput

Tags: .net, networking, monitoring

Good evening,

does anyone know a native/elegant way to read out the available network interfaces and their current througput (e.g. bytes/sec) in .net?

Cheers & thanks,
-Jörg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that information from WMI ...

```
// Reference System.Management
var mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter");
var nics = mos.Get();

foreach (var n in nics)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", n["Name"], n["Speed"]);
}
```

[List of properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(VS.85).aspx) on Win32_NetworkAdapter.

If you want real-time data (which I think you might be asking for), use [PerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) instead.  These correspond to perfmon counters.  For example ...

```
var counter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Total/sec", 
                                      /* your net interface name here */);
Console.WriteLine(counter.RawValue);
```